# Update Excel with ADODB with Workbook Open

Tags: vba, excel, adodb

In Excel 2010. I am trying to write/update some cells, based on some filters, on the same workbook that executes the macro; for simplicity, I have reduced de query to what you can see.
This code works, but only when the workbook is closed (tested from another workbook).

```
Dim libro As Workbook
Set libro = ActiveWorkbook
esteLibro = libro.Name

Dim cnCaja As ADODB.Connection
Dim rsCaja As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnCaja = New ADODB.Connection
Set rsCaja = New ADODB.Recordset
cnCaja.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source='" & esteLibro & "';" & _
        "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;ReadOnly=False';"

Dim consCaja As String
consCaja = "Update [Base$A3:T100000] Set INVERSIONES = 1000 "
rsCaja.Open consCaja, cnCaja, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
```

When executed from another workbook, the column "INVERSIONES" will have its blank cells changed to 10000; but from the same workbook I got the error:

> '-2147217865 (8004e37)' The Microsoft Access database engine could not
>   find the object '[Base$A3:T100000]'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its
>   name and the path name correctly. If '' is not a local object, check
>   your network connection or contact the server administrator.

This is the entire connection string:

```
Debug.Print cnCaja.ConnectionString
```

> Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin; Data
>   Source=Danny_Diario.xlsm;Mode=Share Deny None; Jet OLEDB:System
>   database="";Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=""; Jet OLEDB:Database
>   Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=35; Jet OLEDB:Database Locking
>   Mode=0;Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2; Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk
>   Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password=""; Jet OLEDB:Create
>   System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False; Jet
>   OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False; Jet OLEDB:Compact Without
>   Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False; Jet OLEDB:Support Complex
>   Data=False; Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;

And, a query against the same table will work, even when the workbook is open.

```
consCaja = "Select * from [Base$A3:T100000] Where Fecha = #" & fechaBase & "# and Empresa = ""Empresa"" and Banco = ""Banco"""
rsCaja.Open consCaja, cnCaja, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

Do While Not rsCaja.EOF
    MsgBox (rsCaja("Empresa").Value & vbNewLine & rsCaja("Banco").Value & vbNewLine & rsCaja("INVERSIONES").Value)
    rsCaja.MoveNext
Loop
```

Finally, is it possible to update an Excel with ADODB with the workbook open?
If yes, what am I doing wrong, or how do I resolve this?

Comment: Connection strings need full path. Change top line to: `esteLibro = libro.FullName`. Even still, I doubt you can update with opened workbook.

Comment: I can read, so full path is not necessary. But even with full path, I still have the same error.
And I have been unable to find some source that tells me that this cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

Consider running a read-only `SELECT` over the existing data of the opened workbook. For various reasons of file write access, Excel, being a flat file cached memory application, may not have the facility like databases to have application opened and current data updated synchronously.

Below sets up `SELECT` query for you to mirror current structure with one change of passing a constant, 1000, and assigning it to the *INVERSIONES* column alias in current column position. A conditional logic `IIF` statement can easily be placed here as well. Alternatively, run query and dump results in a new worksheet. Then delete/archive current worksheet and save workbook.

```
Dim cnCaja As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsCaja As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim consCaja As String

esteLibro = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
cnCaja.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source='" & esteLibro & "';" & _
            "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;';"

consCaja = "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, '1000' AS INVERSIONES, Col4, Col5, Col6" & _
           " FROM [Base$A3:T100000]"
rsCaja.Open consCaja, cnCaja

Worksheets("Base").Range("A3").CopyFromRecordset rsCaja

rsCaja.Close: cnCaja.Close
Set rsCaja As Nothing: Set cnCaja As Nothing
```

Comment: That is a simplified query. The real query is something like:
`'consUpdate = "Update [Base$A3:T100000] Set INVERSIONES = prMonto " & _
'                "Where Empresa = prEmpresa and BANCO = prBanco and Fecha = prFecha "`
I want to use a parameterized query, for the filters in SQL, that is why I need ADODB. There could be gaps between the data that I want to update, so I cannot use range.copy...
The other option, for now, is to just loop thru the rows to see if the data match my parameters, but I think it will be a lot slower with time and the increment in data.

Comment: As mentioned you can use an `IIF()` to set logic and pass needed params: `SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, IIF(Empresa = ? AND BANCO = ? AND Fecha =?, ?, INVERSIONES) AS NewInversiones, Col4, Col5, Col6 FROM [Base$A3:T100000]`. And I don't quite understand why `CopyFromRecordset` does not work as it would be exact copy of very table range in `FROM` clause, places right back starting at `Base$A3`.

Comment: Now I understand. But still I am not comfortable with rewriting everything.
Thank you. I suppose that what I want to do is not possible, so I will just use the old `For each r in ws.Range().Rows`.

Comment: I added a field to the Excel sheet with the row number and pulled the value into the query, then updated only the rows I wanted, ws.range("A" & rsCaja("rowNumber"))=1000